Google Ads apicenter access issues
I am trying to get access to the apicenter of google ads through:
I do have an account listed as admin:

Whenever I try to access the api page (https://ads.google.com/aw/apicenter), I get this blurb:

(The API Center is only available to manager accounts. See our API signup guide for more information.
)
Any help would be appreciated.
